# dynamodbをローカルで起動させたい

Tags: aws, amazon-dynamodb

dynamodbをローカルに入れたいのですがawsにある手順通りにjavaのコマンドでインストールしようとしても、dynamodbをローカルがport8000を使う前にjavaがport8000を使うようでインストールが出来ません。

使用ポートの変更などしてdynamodbをローカルインストールなど出来るでしょうか？

[image]

Comment: 実行したコマンドや表示されたメッセージはなるべく画像でなく **文字** 情報として質問文に含めてください。画像で貼り付ける場合でも、必要な範囲を切り抜いてから貼ると確認がしやすいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

直接の解決ではありませんが、DynamoDB Local は Docker 経由でも使うことができます。こちらを使うとうまくいったりしないでしょうか。

```sh
docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local
```

ドキュメントはこのあたりが参考になります。

- https://aws.amazon.com/jp/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.Docker.html